# Put a title on collapsed outlining in Visual Basic Express 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, outlining

When I select an area of text in Visual Basic Express 2010 and then go click Edit/Outlining/Hide Selection; the area collapses and is represented by three dots like "...". Is there a way to put my own title, description or label on it for better meaning and communication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the Region tag?

```
Public Class SomeClass
+   #Region "my special description for Foo"

        Public Sub Foo
            ''# process crap here
        End Sub
    #End Region

+   #Region "a different description for Bar"

        Public Sub Bar
            ''# process crap here
        End Sub
    #End Region
End Class
```

Once you add a "Region" to your code, you can then collapse it and the description stays visible.